# Add Element/Paragraph after html BR?

Tags: jquery, html

Evening all!

I'm having some issues with styling out a few pages on my site. the problem i'm having is the information that's being pulled and displayed on the page has no real styling included, but does just contain `<brs>`which end up rendering my content quite ugly!

I'm looking to see if there's a way i can insert a Paragraph tag, after a BR element, before some text. and then also add a closing paragraph tag after some text, before the BR tag underneath. - Thus putting the text that's between my breaks into paragraphs to allow further styling.

I've dropped an example over on: http://jsfiddle.net/fish_r/9efc8/ -
Here, i've started experimenting with

```
    $( "#property-info p br" ).before( "<p>" );
```

But this just adds a punch of paragraph tags around my BR's rather than around my text.

I don't have much control of the way the information is output onto the page to do it manually.

Comment: You have to differentiate between adding _tags_ (which would mean pure string manipulation), and inserting _elements_ (and be aware what the difference between the two is first of all). `.before` inserts elements, so of course this can not work. You will either have to do string manipulation (get the HTML code for your content first), or create `p` elements, and append the appropriate text nodes to them a child nodes.

Comment: Cheers CBroe. 

I think i've got what you mean, i need to create the elements, find each child text node individually and append these into my elements. 

Do you have any links or information that could be me on the right track to being able to target the text nodes themselves?

Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

D'oh, The .contents() documentation had exactly what i was looking for!

```
$( "#property-info p" )
.contents()
.filter(function() {
return this.nodeType === 3;
})
.wrap( "<p></p>" )
.end()
.filter( "br" )
.remove();
```

has done the job perfectly, removed my breaks and wrapped each node into a P tag :)

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code part. You can set p tag.

```
$( "#property-info p br" ).each(function( index ) {
  //console.log( index + ": " + $( this ).text() );
    $(this).before('<p>');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9efc8/2/

Comment: Thanks for the comment Maverabil, However this has the same effect as the code above unfortunately, it doesn't wrap the text between the Breaks with a paragraph.